# rake db:seed not inputting all of my data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having issues of my `rake db:seed` not being applied to the correct values when I attempt to seed. I also get no error when I `rake db:seed` which is why I am unsure what is wrong.

Here are the migration files:
Boostdets:

```
class CreateBoostdets < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :boostdets do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :title
      t.string :slogan
      t.string :point1
      t.string :point2
      t.string :rating
      t.string :timeframe
      t.string :price
      t.string :image
      t.references :boost
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Boosts:

```
class CreateBoosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :boosts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :slogan
      t.string :rating
      t.string :bonus
      t.string :image
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is a sample of my seed file:

```
b1 = Boost.create(title: "gg", slogan: "Ej", rating: "u", bonus: "y", image: "")
Boostdet.create(name: "t", title: "u", slogan: "y", point1: "t", point2: "rs", rating:  "f",timeframe: "r", price: "Ss", image: "", boost_id: b1.id)
Boostdet.create(name: "g", title: "s", slogan: "x", point1: "e", point2: "Cg", rating: "3", timeframe: "g", price: "t", image: "", boost_id: b1.id)
```

I am unsure what I'm doing wrong since there is no seeding error given it just passes onto the next bash line with no message.

**EDIT**
Models with validation

```
class Boostdet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :boosts
end

class Boost < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :boostdets
end
```

Comment: Do you have validations in your model? If there is could you show it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `boostdets` using the association. This way you don't need to manually pass the `boost_id`

```
boost = Boost.create(title: "gg", slogan: "Ej", rating: "u", bonus: "y", image: "")
boost.boostdets.create(name: "t", title: "u", slogan: "y", point1: "t", point2: "rs", rating:  "f",timeframe: "r", price: "Ss", image: "")
boost.boostdets.create(name: "g", title: "s", slogan: "x", point1: "e", point2: "Cg", rating: "3", timeframe: "g", price: "t", image: "")
```

One more thing you need to change the association `belongs_to :boosts` to `belongs_to :boost`

```
class Boostdet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :boost
end
```

Comment: Infact what actually made my code work was taking the s out of belongs_to :boosts into belongs_to :boost. I do like that i don't have to manually pass the boost_id though. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
b1 = Boost.create(title: "gg", slogan: "Ej", rating: "u", bonus: "y", image: "")
b1.boostdets.create(name: "t", title: "u", slogan: "y", point1: "t", point2: "rs", rating:  "f",timeframe: "r", price: "Ss", image: "")
b1.boostdets.create(name: "g", title: "s", slogan: "x", point1: "e", point2: "Cg", rating: "3", timeframe: "g", price: "t", image: "")
```

And take note if you are using `belongs_to` it should be singular so instead of:

```
belongs_to :boosts
```

it should be:

```
belongs_to :boost
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you please use the build command from rails to create boostdet. Please check the code below,

```
@boost = Boost.create(title: "gg", slogan: "Ej", rating: "u", bonus: "y", image: "")
@boost.create_boostdet(name: "t", title: "u", slogan: "y", point1: "t", point2: "rs", rating:  "f",timeframe: "r", price: "Ss", image: "")
@boost.create_boostdet(name: "g", title: "s", slogan: "x", point1: "e", point2: "Cg", rating: "3", timeframe: "g", price: "t", image: "")
```

Comment: returns undefined method create_boostdet

Comment: The above code is still valid if your belongs_to was correct.
check this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference